# React frontend doesn't receive return from nodejs backend in Reactjs + Nodejs App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bluebird

My backend login process is running on a Nodejs 12.16.1. The code is following:

```
router.post("/elogin", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (!req.body.userName || !req.body.password) throw new Error("No match");  //<<==this line causes error and jump to catch
        let emp = await Employee.findOne({where: {username, password}});
        if (!emp) throw new Error("No match！");
        return res.status(200).send(_.pick(emp, ['id', 'cell', 'cell_country', 'name']))
    } catch(err) {
        return res.status(400).send("Hi Not working right now");  //<<===this return stuck and never come out. 
    }

});
```

In debug the code stuck at `drainQueues` in Bluebird which is a promise library according to online info. The execution never ends and stuck here. This is a normal `return` and I don't see how it shall be stuck.

The front end is React and Fetch. The action type does not matter. The `get` is stuck as well.

[image]

Comment: The problem is between the communication between react and nodejs. I can see the return on a browser from nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use postman to see if it returns. If there is, then there may be a problem with the backend code

Comment: The backend code seems working as I have received the return in browser from API call to nodejs. There is `cors` installed in backend nodejs. Also in React package.json, added a line of "proxy":"http://localhost:5000". What else can be a problem?

Comment: Maybe the problem is here. Are your nodejs and react in the same running environment? And is the port of nodejs 5000? If neither,
The "proxy" you configured: localhost:5000 does not take effect. If you use react-create-app, the proxy needs a special config file